How to Drag QLineEdit form one cell of QGridLayout to other cell in pyqt?
I have gridlayout with four cells (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1). Every cell is vertical layout with scrollbar. Initially only (0,0) cell contains QLineEdit in it. I want to drag and drop them in any one of the cells. How can I do it? I want to layout the cells like the image contained in the following link.

I have tried this code
main.py :
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from mywidgets import MyWidget

from myui import Ui_Form 



class MainWidget(MyWidget, Ui_Form):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.show()
        
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

mywidgets.py :
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QWidget, QScrollArea

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap

class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            
    
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        pos = e.pos()
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('accepted but not moved , there is no layout')
        print('pos : ', pos)
        print('event.source : ', widget , 'event.source.parent() :', widget.parent())
        
        widget.setParent(None)
        
        print('parent : ', self.parent())
        
        widget.show()
    
            
class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    
    pass

my PyQt5-designer ui file translated with pyuic5 ;
myui.py :
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(698, 635)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = MyScrollArea(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -219, 315, 561))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_1 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.lineEdit_4 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.lineEdit_5 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.lineEdit_15 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15)
        self.lineEdit_14 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14)
        self.lineEdit_13 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13)
        self.lineEdit_12 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12)
        self.lineEdit_11 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11)
        self.lineEdit_10 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10)
        self.lineEdit_9 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9)
        self.lineEdit_8 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8)
        self.lineEdit_7 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.lineEdit_6 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_2 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 305))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_3 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setObjectName("scrollArea_3")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 304))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_4 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setObjectName("scrollArea_4")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 304))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_4")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.lineEdit_15.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.lineEdit_14.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.lineEdit_13.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(_translate("Form", "10"))
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(_translate("Form", "11"))
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(_translate("Form", "12"))
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(_translate("Form", "13"))
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(_translate("Form", "14"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(_translate("Form", "15"))


    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            


from mywidgets import MyLineEdit, MyScrollArea, MyWidget

but it is not working:

output printed:
accepted but not moved , there is no layout
pos :  PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(27, 95)
event.source :  <mywidgets.MyLineEdit object at ........> 
event.source.parent() : <mywidgets.MyWidget object at ........>
parent :  <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget object at ......>

I want to drag elements from (0,0) cell and drop anyone of the cell such that it will remove from cell (0,0) and add in layout of cell where it dropped. Every cell contains a scrollbar because there can be many elements in each cell.
I guess is something related to layout and widget , not able in designer to add a layout without widgets in cell (0,1) ,(1.-,0) and (1,1) , and still have problem getting the layout out of a position in PyQt

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Don't tell us that what you tried doesn't work: show us what you tried. Please take your time to provide a proper [mre] (and please do read that link, we don't need the full code, but the minimal code that allows us to reproduce the problem), then [edit] your post and include it, explaining what happens when you run it and any problem related to its behavior.

the image you linked is not the result of the code you linked

Hi @musicmante , I have edited the code Which I am using. Please provide me some solution. I am a beginner so it's my first time of creating drag & drop in Pyqt.

@musicamante tried to get minimal code to Kskrishna question , hopefully it has some meaning

OK kind of solved the layout problem thanks to an old post I used some time ago that went nearly forgotten answer to How to make QScrollArea working properly

Alternatively, you can also do the same from Designer with a small workaround:


add any widget (a button, a label, it doesn't matter) to the scrollAreaWidgetContents widget; you actually already have such a widget (the gridLayoutWidget_2 you created inside it), so you could use that for this purpose;


right click on the scroll area and select grid layout from the "Lay out" sub menu;


remove the widget added before (or the gridLayoutWidget_2 in your case);


This is required because Designer doesn't allow to set a layout for a widget until it has at least one child widget.

That explain how to create an empty layout in PyQt-Designer .
My revised code ;
main.py :
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from mywidgets import MyWidget

from myui import Ui_Form 



class MainWidget(MyWidget, Ui_Form):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.show()
        
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

mywidgets.py :
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QWidget, QScrollArea

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QCursor


class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        e.ignore()
    
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            
    
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        pos = e.pos()
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('accepted but not moved , there is no layout')
        print('pos : ', pos, 'mouse : ', QCursor.pos())
        print('event.source : ', widget , 'event.source.parent() :', widget.parent())
        
        widget.setParent(None)
        
        print('parent : ', self.parent() , self.parent().objectName())
        
        print('self.layput() : ', self.layout())
        
        print('self.objectName() : ', self.objectName())
        
        #widget.show() # not needed its shown in layout
        
        if self.layout() != None :
            
            self.layout().addWidget(e.source())
            
class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    
    pass

my PyQt5-Designer ui file translated with pyuic5 ;
myui.py :
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(698, 635)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = MyScrollArea(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 897))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_1 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.lineEdit_4 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.lineEdit_5 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.lineEdit_15 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15)
        self.lineEdit_14 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14)
        self.lineEdit_13 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13)
        self.lineEdit_12 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12)
        self.lineEdit_11 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11)
        self.lineEdit_10 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10)
        self.lineEdit_9 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9)
        self.lineEdit_8 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8)
        self.lineEdit_7 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.lineEdit_6 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_2 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 305))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_3 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setObjectName("scrollArea_3")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 304))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_4 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setObjectName("scrollArea_4")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 304))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.lineEdit_15.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.lineEdit_14.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.lineEdit_13.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(_translate("Form", "10"))
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(_translate("Form", "11"))
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(_translate("Form", "12"))
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(_translate("Form", "13"))
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(_translate("Form", "14"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(_translate("Form", "15"))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            


from mywidgets import MyLineEdit, MyScrollArea, MyWidget


Picture of results:

Only big problem with this setup is that when QLineEdit-Widgets
get dragged and dropped around they are added to the layout at the end of it,
don't know how to insert them in the exact position where they are dropped, to me  is not an easy problem to solve

thank you @pippo, It is really helpful and resolve my problem.

OK went a little bit further:
My revised code ;
main.py :
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

from myui_bis import Ui_Form 


class MainWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printAcceptDrops)
        
        self.show()
        
    def printAcceptDrops(self):
        
        print('printAcceptDrops : ')

        print('Mainwidget : ', self.acceptDrops())

        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.acceptDrops())       
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.acceptDrops())   
        print('self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 : ', self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.acceptDrops()) 
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

my mywidgets.py :
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QWidget, QScrollArea, QScroller

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QCursor

from PyQt5 import QtGui

from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):

        print('ENTER DRAG EVENT IN ', self.objectName())
        
        e.accept()
        
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('\n dropped on widget !!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n')
        
        
        if widget == self :
            
            return
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   qlineedit')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)
        
       
        widget.setParent(None)
        
self.parent().layout().insertWidget(self.parent().layout().indexOf(self) , widget)
       
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
            
            
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        print('ENTER DRAG EVENT IN ', self.objectName())
        
        print('self.layout.count()', self.layout().count())
        
        e.accept()
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        pos = e.pos()
        
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('pos : ', pos, 'mouse : ', QCursor.pos())
        print('event.source : ', widget , 'event.source.parent() :', widget.parent())
        
        print('event.source  name: ', widget.objectName()) 
        
        print('parent : ', self.parent() , self.parent().objectName())
        
        print('self.layput() : ', self.layout())
        
        print('self.objectName() : ', self.objectName())
        
        if widget.parent().layout().count() == 1:
            
            print('=============== 1   WIDGET')
            
            widget.parent().layout().parent().setAcceptDrops(True)

        if self.layout().count() == 0 :
            
            widget.setParent(None)
            
            self.layout().addWidget(widget)
            
            self.setAcceptDrops(False)
            
        
class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(MyScrollArea, self).__init__(parent)
           

my PyQt5-Designer ui file translated with pyuic5 myui_bis :
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(698, 672)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea_3 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setObjectName("scrollArea_3")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 303))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_4 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setObjectName("scrollArea_4")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 303))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_2 = MyScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 315, 304))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea = MyScrollArea(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = MyWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -304, 315, 897))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(30)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_1 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.lineEdit_3 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3)
        self.lineEdit_4 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4)
        self.lineEdit_5 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5)
        self.lineEdit_15 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15)
        self.lineEdit_14 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14)
        self.lineEdit_13 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13)
        self.lineEdit_12 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12)
        self.lineEdit_11 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11)
        self.lineEdit_10 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10)
        self.lineEdit_9 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9)
        self.lineEdit_8 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8)
        self.lineEdit_7 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7)
        self.lineEdit_6 = MyLineEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.lineEdit_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.lineEdit_15.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.lineEdit_14.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.lineEdit_13.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.lineEdit_12.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.lineEdit_11.setText(_translate("Form", "10"))
        self.lineEdit_10.setText(_translate("Form", "11"))
        self.lineEdit_9.setText(_translate("Form", "12"))
        self.lineEdit_8.setText(_translate("Form", "13"))
        self.lineEdit_7.setText(_translate("Form", "14"))
        self.lineEdit_6.setText(_translate("Form", "15"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Check AcceptDrops"))

from mywidgets import MyLineEdit, MyScrollArea, MyWidget

Now, the QLineEdit Widgets are added to the scrollAreas layouts when these are empty but then their acceptDrops attribute is set to False and the next QLineEdit widgets have to be dropped on the already present ones taking their layout-index positions within the layouts. When no widgrts are left in a layout its acceptDrops value is set to True again.
Only big problem now is that I cannot scroll and drag at the same time in any of the four scrollAreas, but that glitch was present in the previous answer too.

Clicking the Check AcceptDrops QPushButton you get the widgets acceptDrops() values:
printAcceptDrops : 
Mainwidget :  False
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents :  False
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 :  False
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 :  True
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 :  True

