How to force Designer to keep QScrollAreas in QGridLayout of same size during resize in PyQt5?
Code main.py:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QScrollArea, QWidget, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout


from PyQt5 import QtGui , uic

from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag



class MainWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        uic.loadUi('test006-001.ui' , self)
    
        self.show()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    # w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

test006-001.ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>698</width>
    <height>635</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
     <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
      <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>-37</y>
        <width>315</width>
        <height>598</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_13"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_5"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_12"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_11"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_6"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_16"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_14"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_7"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_15"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_8"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_9"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_10"/>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="1">
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea_2">
     <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
      <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>315</width>
        <height>305</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea_3">
     <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
      <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>315</width>
        <height>304</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="1">
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea_4">
     <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
      <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>315</width>
        <height>304</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>

I tried different size policies etc in Designer, but cannot accomplish my goal of having always the four QScrollAreas of same size while resizing my main Widget, I get it only at full screen and smallest size:

but not at intermediate sizes:

Any idea about how to force keeping same size while resizing?

Select the Form in the object inspector, and in the property editor set both layoutRowStretch and layoutColumnStretch to 1,1.

any change to have it reopened , just that I can put correct ui and a pics of layout setting Column and RowStretch , I'll mark it as a duplicate again later on ? the duplicate doesnt use designer so its not exactly the same

by the way, of course your answer is correct thank @musicamante , still trying to get the basis for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78370120/how-to-drag-qlineedit-form-one-cell-of-qgridlayout-to-other-cell-in-pyqt#comment138173614_78370120
